# Como mapear os resultados de uma store procedure com uma entidade usando Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mvc

Fala pessoal. Estou fazendo um projeto com MVC 4 e EF6.

Gostaria de chamar uma proc e os resultados dela populassem uma entidade. Porém minha entidade não é uma tabela do banco, por isso não usei Dbset nela. O que acontece é que essa proc faz join de algumas tabelas. Estou fazendo tudo via codigo, pois o banco ja existia e tem muita coisa que não vou usar.

Essa é minha entidade

```
public class Dados
{
    public string dtAnoMes { get; set; }
    public string valor{ get; set; }
    public string valorTotal { get; set; }
    public string dif { get; set; }

    public Dados()
    { }

    public IList<Dados> RecuperaValores(string data)
    {
        using (var context = new ContextoBanco())
        {
            var dtInicio = new SqlParameter("@Value1", data);
            var dtFim = new SqlParameter("@Value2", data);

            var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<Dados>("SP_RECUPERA_VALORES @Value1, @Value2", dtInicio , dtFim ).ToList();


            return result.ToList();
        }
    }

}
```

Minha proc retorna quatro colunas: ANO/MES, VALOR, VALOR_TOTAL, DIFERENCA.

queria de alguma forma falar que a coluna ANO/MES equivale a propriedade dtANoMes da entidade e assim por diantes. O codigo de executar a proc está funcionando de boa. só falta esse map. Alguém sabe como posso fazer?

Muito Obrigado!

**ATUALIZADO**

Consegui resolver atualizando meu Entity Framework pra versão 6, e usando MapToStoredProcedures. Mas ainda estou procurando uma annotation que mapeie minha propriedade com a coluna de retorno da proc, apenas por perfumaria mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode mapear um DbSet para uma storedprocedure no contexto

```
public DbSet<Dados> Dados { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Dados>().MapToStoredProcedures();
}
```

Vou deixar como referência este arquivo do Renato Haddad no MSDN falando sobre Stored Procedures no EF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn720414.aspx

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Mas estranho, nao tenho esse maptostoredprocedures rs.

Comment: Qual a versão do Entity que está utilizando? Pois estas chamadas existem no EF 6 pra frente

Comment: Acho que era isso, estava na versao 5 rsrs. muito obrigado.

Comment: vixi, agora está falando que minha entidade Dados não tem um key definida. e realmente eu nao tenho uma key, pq essa entidade não é uma tabela, eu criei ela apenas para receber os dados da proc.

Comment: Se olharmos a convenção do Ef, se colocar uma coluna com Id na procedure já resolve. Se ANO/MES não repetir, coloca o Attribute [Key] acima da propriedade que o EF vai entender que ele é a chave.

Comment: entendi. a coluna anomes repete muito. nenhuma das colunas q a proc volta é unico. eu vou criar uma propriedade na entidade pra ser a chave e ver se consigo alterar a proc pra retornar uma coluna unica.

Comment: Muito obrigado viu. deu certo aqui. criei uma prop 'id' e coloquei um row_number as 'id' na minha proc, ai ele mapeou. só preciso agora mapear as outras props com as outras colunas, não queria colocar o mesmo nome nas props, mas se nao tiver jeito eu deixo os nomes iguais.